# What is the Relationship between Fiber tree and Virtual DOM in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When I'm learning about how React works under the hood, I’m confusing Fiber trees and VirtualDOMs. I have got Some article says React maintains one VirtaulDOM and two Fiber tree. I have heard React maintains two VirtualDOMs like updated and pre-updated to compare?

I need to know what is the relationship with Fiber tree and VirtualDOM.

Comment: I don't see a specific question.

Comment: Which article(s) did you read?

Comment: @JSONDerulo My question is what is the relationship Fiber tree and Virtual DOM? and Does React maintains two VirtualDOM and two Fiber trees at the same time?

Comment: @Bergi I have read [blogs](https://indepth.dev/react) here and medium articles also. Do you know any specific blogs or videos that describes these concepts well.